# Should I be using JDBC getNString() instead of getString()?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, nvarchar

We are building a Java application backed by an Oracle database that we access using JDBC (drivers `ojdbc6.jar` and `orai18n.jar`). The database schema stores text columns primarily using the `NVARCHAR2` data type.

The [JDBC documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getNString%28int%29) for the JDBC `ResultSet` says that `getNString()` is particularly intended for use with the NCHAR, NVARCHAR etc. data types, but at the moment we are only using `getString()`.

This seems to work fine, so I am wondering why I should use `getNString()` rather than `getString()`. Is `getString()` going to start failing if non-ASCII characters are entered, or is the Oracle JDBC driver indifferent as to which method I should use?

EDIT: Seems that it may be database-dependent: [SQL Server doesn't seem to mind which you use](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/8e0d9743-241e-4b09-b3a2-137238c02bf1), depending on the connection parameters. Does anyone have any specific information on Oracle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have done a test on our application and it seems that `getNString()` is unnecessary with Java 6, JDBC 6, Oracle JDBC 6 drivers and Oracle 11.1.0.6.0. The test string I used was "Δ, Й, ק, ‎ م, ๗, あ, 叶, 葉, and 말", copied from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode.

Most of our data access is done via stored procedures. Java was able to set and retrieve the above test string correctly via `setObject()` and `getString()` (not `setString()` for abstraction reasons), collecting data from the interface and writing it back to the interface as expected.

Hence `getString()` works ok for Unicode data with Oracle 11g (like SQL Server as in the above link) so we will continue to use this rather than `getNString()`.

Comment: I suggest you add that test to your regression suite in case it changes in future versions of Oracle or Java

Comment: @artbristol - that's a very good idea. Even a change in Oracle configuration could potentially cause a regression (although I have no reason to believe that except for experience with Oracle configuration)

Comment: this is a sign of poorly designed API by Java.

Answer (score 2):

If your DB uses the `NVARCHAR2` datatype, it is designed to be storing multilingual data. Your program will break if any unicode data is stored in those columns. If I were you, I would move over to the `getNXXX()` methods

Comment: You can not getNString on varchar column in sql server. So there is no global solution. oracle java driver handles nvarchar - varchar conversion but mssql driver does not